# How to change Ubuntu 18 name and logo in details?

Tags: gnome

I got an assignment to make another distro based on ubuntu 18. Recently I got stuck at this step. I have no idea how to change Ubuntu 18.04 text and icon logo in details settings (Settings > Details)

I did search on YouTube and many other online forums, but I only found tutorial for Ubuntu 14.04 (unity) which is completely different and can't be done in Ubuntu 18.04(gnome).

Please anyone help me.

Comment: Is this a work assignment or a school assignment?

Comment: This is school assignment

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work man. :(

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10, the logo is located at `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/ubuntu-logo-icon.png`

[image]

and the text under that logo or "Ubuntu version" is from the file `/usr/lib/os-release` under "PRETTY_NAME"

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.10"
VERSION_ID="18.10"
```

After customizing here is the "About" section:

[image]