# How to change OS name in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lsb-release

I already change the lsb-release, but when i checked it on the lsb_release -a it didnt change anything. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What did you change (and why) .. please update your question with what you changed, which commands you run, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1106645/739431 is it related?

Answer (score 3):

you should not change the distro name in lsb-release or in os-release, that will arise problem for you. My advice is that if you want to change the distro name for the purpose of customization, so as to make it look like other OS, then you should change the "Pretty name" in /etc/os-release
and then type `neofetch` in the terminal.

Here you can see, I am using `Ubuntu 20.04` but I changed the OS name to `macOS 10.15 Catalina.`

NOTE: Do not edit lsb-release or os-release as it may create problems for applications like Software center.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. it works perfectly